# If a product is assembled in a specific country, what is the impact of an export ban covering that product and that country?

Tags: sanctions, export

The USA recently announced an export ban for certain high-performance AI computing components in China and around 50 other countries around the world. Notably, this affects the Nvidia Geforce RTX 4090, a top of the line gaming graphics card that's also suitable for AI computing due to the large amount of volatile VRAM video memory.

The thing is that Nvidia doesn't make most of these cards. It just designs the central GPU, which in turn is manufactured in Taiwan by TSMC and shipped to factories around the world for assemblage into complete graphics cards. This includes factories in China like those of MSI, ASUS, Zotac and others.

Wouldn't the export ban effectively mean that these companies can no longer manufacture these cards, even for customers outside of the country? And if the export ban doesn't apply to these companies, what prevents these products from being distributed from these factories in China directly to China, either by the owners of the factory or through the Chinese government seizing these products?

Comment: Note: I am uncertain if the tags are correct, so any edits to improve them are appreciated.

Comment: Most of this seems to be legal question not economic one. Also as you correctly ask in the last part these kinda sanctions are nearly impossible to harshly enforce since people can always export it to friendly but corrupt country and then some unknown business can just reexport them

Comment: PS: if you want I can more this to Law.SE I think it would fit it there better

Comment: @1muflon1 I think moving it to Law.SE might be better yeah. I wasn't entirely sure where to ask this, and I thought considering this is about exports, economics was the best place, but again, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Ok I will migrate it, question about exports is usually economics question, but you are asking about **legal** export restrictions

Comment: As to the title question, each specific sanction law has to be analyzed separately and the fine print of the relevant law very much matters.